# Prioritize the table view cells IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to prfioritize the tableView cells in order to display at the top of tableView in the mothod `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?
I want to display the priority cells at the top of the tableView cells checking if they have priority or not, depending on the `bool` value of `havePriority` property, such that if `havePriority` is 1, it should be true else should be after the priority list.
I've tried by using different cell identifiers but unable to got the list at the top.

**My Code:**

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
 if (havePriority) // if the cell wants priority to be at top, have a value in bool
    {
        cell.textLabel = sOmeText; // 
        NSLog(@"%@",sOmeText);
    }
    return cell;
```

Comment: Prioritize your dataSource, then reloadData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be setting the order of the cells in that method. By then it is far too late.

This is really something that should be done in the model layer. The list of items to be displayed should already be sorted according to their priority, and that way they will show up at the top.

Secondarily, this type of code isn't really necessary anymore:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

You should be using the more modern method:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                                              forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

This will either return a cell from the reuse pool or create a new one, so it always returns a cell, and there is no need to create one yourself.

Comment: it is giving this error: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Comment: Which is what you should be doing. Either use the cell identifier from the storyboard or xib file, or use the methods `
registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`

Comment: I've declared in storyborad and its done, can u please explain a bit more that whats the difference between old and modern approch?

Comment: It's in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: